# Is there difference between 大事／大した

Tags: word-choice, usage

When would one be used? I don't understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

事【じ】 is a matter, so 大事【だいじ】means a "serious matter".

大【たい】した places less emphasis on the "matter" and more on being "big", so can simply mean "very" or "much".

As an example

> 国家安全保障【こっかあんぜんほしょう】の大事【だいじ】 - a matter of national security

and

> 彼女【かのじょ】は大【たい】した歌手【かしゅ】になるはず - she will definitely become a (very big) singer

As per their negative counterparts, I find that in a colloquial sentence the following would seem a bit more formal:

> 大事【だいじ】ではない ー (it's not a big issue)

whereas this sounds more natural:

> 大【たい】したこと（では）ない ー (no biggie)

Comment: I've seen the last one shortened to 大したことない as well.

Comment: Yep, I thought about that too. I've added the parentheses around the optional では